# defaulting a structure field of a class in a constructor

Tags: c++, class, structure, default

So suppose I have a type named donut. I would like to make a constructor for donut that takes 3 arguments, two ints, and a structure cream which has two integers as fields. I would like to put default values for the arguments in case there are no supplied arguments. So how would the syntax be?

```
Donut::Donut(int a=0, int b=0, cream car={0, 0})

                    : donutfield1(a), donutfield2(b), donutfield3(car) { }
```

this does not work...

Comment: first time the code made me hungry

Comment: haha.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Donut::Donut(int a=0, int b=0, cream car=cream{0, 0})
```

(in fact your code *should* compile on a C++11 conforming compiler, but if it doesn't, the above will hopefully help)

Comment: Hmm... C++11 allows `={0, 0}` as well as `=cream{0, 0}` while C++03 AFAIK only allows `=cream(0, 0)` (note the parentheses)... At least g++ tells me that.

Comment: @leemes Right. Hm, I thought that C++ without the C++03 tag and given what the OP tried suggests he is using a (wannabe) C++11 compiler. If this is indeed C++03, the round brackets are the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is introduced in C++11 (it's called *extended initializer lists*). For your code to be compatible with C++03, use the old syntax:

```
Donut::Donut(int a=0, int b=0, cream car = cream(0, 0)) ...
```

Note that if your class (here `cream`) provides a constructor with a *single* parameter and doesn't use the `explicit` keyword, it can be constructed from an instance of the type of the parameter without any brackets or parentheses, e.g. `cream car = 0`.